# Can I continue working while git pushes?

Tags: git, git-push

I am doing my initial import of existing code into git, it is quite a big codebase so the push is taking it's time.

From what I am aware git gets the changes and then does the upload, so am I safe to continue working while the push is going, or do I need to wait for it to complete before I modify the files?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When Git pushes, it doesn't read or write anything from the working tree, only stuff from the `.git` folder.

So yes, you're safe to continue working.

Comment: But I am assuming the reverse is true for pulls as they do modify the working tree? e.g. If I had not pulled in a few months and then did I would have to wait for that to complete yes?

Comment: `pull` is a short cut for `fetch`+`merge`. `fetch` doesn't change your files, `merge` obviously does. If you have slow connection, maybe you could do `fetch` while working and then `merge` when you decide to bring remote changes into your working tree.

Comment: What about making commits while pushing? Won't this change things in the `.git` folder?